# How to debug the server (kestrel) of aspnet core

Tags: asp.net-core

I ran my head against a issue where i have no idea how to continue.

In short my problem is that the request finishes the aspnet core pipeline as everything being okay. But the content never reach the browser.

[image: issue]

Testing in postman where it it tells me there was an error connecting. But when debugger is enabled i can step all the way through the aspnet core pipeline and nothing is faulting. Their build in logger also tells me a 200 is returned.

Adding

```
 app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            ctx.Response.OnCompleted(c =>
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },null);
```

also trigger the on completed, so all indicates that the aspnet pipeline runs that it works. All integration tests also work with the in mem test server.

When i invoke it from the browser, the loading spinner just keeps running and the request never comes up in the network tab, so nothing to help me figure out why this fails.

What can I do to find out why its not working. Can i get some debugger/logging on the kestrel server to see if it writes out exceptions?

Comment: Intermediate result : I think that the issue is that application code adds headers to HttpContext Response after it started writing the body. This makes sense but it do not seem to throw exceptions but only break the underlaying server and connection.

Comment: If you use Jetbrains Rider it will automatically step into 3rd party code when debugging so you might be able to debug the MS code